# Music Bot discord.js issue, Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a hydra-style bot discord with an embed that automatically gets assigned control reactions with which I can pause, resume, stop the music etc ...

I have a problem, if I try to start the command to pause typing '*psres' everything works fine, however, if I try to start the pause command via the reaction it gives me the following error:

> ```
> (node:20172) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined
>     at Object.execute (C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\botdiscord\commands\psres.js:9:40)
>     at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\botdiscord\commands\setup.js:41:53)
> ```

This is my setup.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'setup',
    description: "music embed with reaction",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
        
        const channel = '831573587579371580';
        const playem = '⏯️';
        const stopem = '⏹️';  
        const nextem = '⏭️';
        const shuffleem = '';
        const casualem = '';
      
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       
        .setColor('#e42643')
        .setTitle('Barman')
        .setImage('https://images4.alphacoders.com/943/943845.jpg') 
        .setFooter('il prefisso del bot è: *');     
        
        console.log('message: ' + message )
        console.log('args: ' + args)
        console.log('Discord: ' + Discord)
        console.log('client: ' + client)
    
           let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
           messageEmbed.react(playem);
           messageEmbed.react(stopem);
           messageEmbed.react(nextem); 
           messageEmbed.react(shuffleem); 
           messageEmbed.react(casualem);
           
           client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) =>{
               if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
               if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
               if (user.bot) return;
               if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
               if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel){
                   
                    if (reaction.emoji.name ===  playem){
                        console.log('pause/resume');                    
                       client.commands.get('psres').execute(message, client, args) //line of error
                    }
                } 
           });
           
    }
}
```

This is my pause/resume command:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

const { COLOR } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
  name: "psres", 
  description: "pause/resume",
  async execute (client, message, args) {
    const { channel } = message.member.voice; /line of error
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor(COLOR);
      
    if (!channel) {
      embed.setAuthor("Devi essere in un canale vocale!")
      return message.channel.send(embed);
    }

    const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
    //prova
    if (!serverQueue) {
        embed.setAuthor("Non c'è nulla che possa mettere in pausa")
        return message.channel.send(embed);
      }
      
      if(serverQueue && serverQueue.playing) {
        serverQueue.playing = false;
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause(true)
        
        embed.setDescription("✅ | Canzone messa in pausa")
        embed.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        return message.channel.send(embed)
    } else if(serverQueue && !serverQueue.playing) {
      serverQueue.playing = true;
      serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.resume()
  embed.setAuthor("✅ | Riprendi")
   embed.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
  return message.channel.send(embed)
 }
    embed.setDescription("Non c'è nulla che io possa riprendere")
    message.channel.send(embed)
    
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup.js file the command handler is `client.commands.get('psres').execute(message, client, args)` with message, client and args as parameters. But in the pause/resume command file, you are executing `execute (client, message, args)` with client, message and args as param. The objects are not what you think it is because if you compare both of them, the parameters are not matching/placed in wrong order. So matching the parameters either according to the setup commands param or the way you are executing in the pause/resume command.

Comment: thank you very much, now it works, it was really a stupid mistake

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you.